# Trigger Button Click events across forms progmatically in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

A few insights before I go into the details of my query.

1) I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, with the latest updates as of now.
2) The project I'm working on is a desktop based student management system, developed using C#.

I have 7 forms, Welcome, Login, Registration Form, Student Portal, Professor Portal, and Registrar Portal, and a Help form.
The Registrar portal has 5 buttons, each linked to show its usercontrol
So, basically I have in each form, a help button.

The welcome page help button will open the main Help form.

In the Help, it also has 5 buttons
each button links to a seperate user control that displays instructions for each form.

[Help Form Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCKVB.jpg)

Here, the coding for the Login Page help button has this;

```
private void LoginHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            registrationFormPage1.Hide();
            studentPortalPage1.Hide();
            professorPortalPage1.Hide();
            registrarPortalPage1.Hide();
            welcomeHelp1.Hide();
            loginPage1.Show();
        }
```

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfIe8.jpg)

See the little help button the top right corner?
When I press that button, I want it to open the Help Page main form, and initiate the LoginPageHelp onclick even so it shows up as shown below;

[Help Page with Login Form User Control Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asVOu.jpg)

Since the main Help form page is also meant to be able to be accessed I am out of ideas.

I was hoping to pass a value from the button click event on the Login form so that I can introduce a control structure block that loads OnLoad when the Form is launched so that it checks if any value is passed against it's parameters and initiate the corresponding button click event.

As far as I know, it isn't possible to pass values across forms from with a button click event.

Any insights to how I can achieve my goal?

P.S: I want to specifically see how it could be done with a button click event. I know I can just show and hide user controls but i'm interested to learn how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the cleanest and the most appropriate way to organize your code but if you want just to "pass values across forms from with a button click event" you should create a public variable which is accessible from any section of your project and this variable value can define the desired behavior of whatever you like.
Again this is a messy and error prone coding behavior but it works.

Comment: Yeah, that is an option, but I'm hoping there could be a better way to do this.

Comment: @crxssrazr93 I think it is the only option but of course there can be many ways to do it.
One clean way is to add a dedicated global variables class to your namespace

`namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static string GLOBALSTRING;
        public static int GLOBALINT;
        public static List<object> GLOBALLIST = new List<object>();
        // And so on ...

    }
}`

Comment: You may also consider the MVVM approach it can be very handy in situations similar to your login system. And that's the cleanest way to slove your problem.
However if you are specifically after just passing vlaues between forms, the global varirable is your best option.